# SQL Script to delete old backups matching a certain naming convention?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to have a T-SQL statement that will delete files older than a day in a directory, but only if they match a certain naming convention.  There are multipul backup files in this directory, but only one set we need to keep for a day.  I'm unable to use a maintenance cleanup task because it will clear out all bak files, instead of only the ones I want.

Will using the  `dbo.xp_delete` allow the user of the wildcard character %?

Comment: Why do you need to delete files from the filesystem in SQL? So many other things are better at this: C#, PowerShell, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This feature doesn't seem well documented at all. From what you can read in the comments here you get the general idea of the function:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2009/03/11/xp-delete-file.aspx

I would suggest you write a clean-up task outside of the sql server. This can be easily done with a bat-script or a Powershell script. You can execute these scripts with windows tasks or, in case of a Powershell script, even from within SQL Server itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this through a SQL Server [Maintenance Plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191002.aspx).  Look at the "Maintenance Cleanup Task".  You can clean up files using a variety of criteria, including age and filename.

> This task uses the EXEC xp_delete_file statement.